# How to add a second legend for stat_summary point below prop legend in geom_count ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a geom_count plot and add the mean values of the Y-axis (importance) as points using stat_summary. I would like the shape of the point (red rectangle in my case) to be part of the legend so that it is clear that these are the means. How can I get the means symbol to show up in the legend below the prop legend?

```
#example data:
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                   y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1))

#plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y =  y)) +
 geom_count(aes(size= after_stat(prop), group=x)) + 
 theme_bw() +
 scale_size_area(max_size = 8) +
 stat_summary(
   geom = "point",
   fun = "mean",
   col = "black",
   size = 6,
   shape = 23,
   fill = "red",
   show.legend = F) +
 xlab("") +
 ylab("Importance") + 
 scale_y_continuous(labels=c("1" = "Not at all", "2" = "Little ", "3" = "Moderate", "4" = "Quite"  , "5" =  "Very")) +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, vjust = 1, hjust=1),
       axis.text.y = element_text(angle =30))
```

[image: Click here for plot]

Changing to `show.legend = T` does not solve the problem
[image]

I've tried the solution suggested in [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740583/add-legend-for-a-custom-stat-summary-fun-data) but could not get it to work in my graph. [Using the suggestions of this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756358/how-to-include-in-legend-symbol-of-mean-in-boxplot-with-ggplot) I added the code

```r
  geom_point(aes(shape = "mean"), alpha = 0)+  
  guides(shape=guide_legend(title=NULL, override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

... which has helped me add a means point to the legend, but I wasn't able to add the right shape [(see this plot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF4C1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scale_shape_manual`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                 y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1))

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y =  y)) +
  geom_count(aes(size= after_stat(prop), group=x)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 8) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Importance") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=c("1" = "Not at all", "2" = "Little ", "3" = "Moderate", "4" = "Quite"  , "5" =  "Very")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, vjust = 1, hjust=1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle =30)) +

  # Stat_summary and legend
  stat_summary(fun = mean, aes(shape = "Mean"), geom = 'point', col = "black", fill = "red", size = 6) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("Mean" = 23))
```

[image]